# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, connection

I tried restarting the Mysql server but its not working for me. I am sure the server is running and the permissions on the folder `/var/lib/mysql/` are correct (777).

When i tried to open the file mysql.sock, its giving me an error saying the file may be corrupt.

Please help me log in to DB. Thanks in advance.

This is how My.cnf looks

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysq
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
#Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
```

Comment: give the contents of your /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, as well as your /mnt/data/*.err logs, and it'll be easier to help you. also see if you can login via mysqladmin or anything like that

Comment: try explicitly using the localhost address: 127.0.0.1

Comment: I tried `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -p` too but it did not work

Comment: Are you actually missing the final `l` in `mysql` on the first line, or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 3):

mysqld has to be started in order of the mysql.sock to be created and access by any process. check whether it is running.

I had same issue and checked whether the mysqld was running and I found out that is wasn't, so I started mysqld. That should resolve the problem.

Comment: Yours helped me! Just in case:  `sudo service mysqld start`

Answer (score 0):

As what you have give from your my.cnf .

Please make sure that both socket points to same file.You are missing it.Please make it sure.
Change it as i have changed

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
#Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
```

your both sockets are pointing to different files.

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago. I updated my machine and the socket ceased to work. My solution was to change the socket to a location where it could be opened by every process.

In /etc/mysql/my.cnf (or where this file is)

```
    [client]
    port = 3306
    #socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    socket = /tmp/mysqld.sock # This location did it for me


    [mysqld_safe]
    #socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    socket = /tmp/mysqld.sock 
    ...

    [mysqld]
    ...
    #socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    socket = /tmp/mysqld.sock
    ...
```

It seems important that all the profiles use the same socket. Also you would want to change the /etc/mysql/debian.cnf and update the socket. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unless the mysqld service is running the mysql.sock file is not present in the directory /var/lib/mysql; Please start the mysqld using service mysqld start as root user;

and then run mysql from shell to start the mysql database; This worked for me with same error message;

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the permissions, owner and group on files for the `/var/lib/mysql` directory, as well as the files within it.

I had a similar issue causes when i moved the `/var/lib/mysql` directory to a new machine.  During the copy the permissions were changed, and the owner and group were changed to root.  Changing the owner and group (`chown user:group file/directory`) and permissions (`chmod <value> filename/s`) to the MySQL admin account resolved the issue.